# If <a name="..."> is obsolete, what is preferred?

Tags: html, w3c, obsolete

The HTML code `<a name="some_bookmark">text</a>` is very useful for creating links to specific sections of a page (e.g., `page.html#some_bookmark`). However, the W3C spec now marks the `name` attribute of the `a` tag as "obsolete."

If this is the case, then what is preferred? Is there a new `<bookmark>` tag or similar?

Comment: This question has already been asked here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/12798/10884

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can place an `id=""` attribute on any element and it will have the same effect.

These are typically placed on heading elements.

Comment: name and id are not interchangeable. id must be unique for the entire page and name can be repeated.

Answer (score 13):

Have a look at the HTML5 spec.

At [Obsolete features](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete) you’ll find:

> Authors should not specify the `name` attribute on `a` elements.

When clicking on [`name`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-a-name), you’ll find:

> [The following attributes are obsolete (though the elements are still part of the language), and must not be used by authors:]
>
> - `name` on `a` elements (except as noted in the previous section)
> - `name` on `embed` elements
> - `name` on `img` elements
> - `name` on `option` elements
>
> → Use the `id` attribute instead.

Click on [`id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). You’ll see that `id` is a [global attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes), this means that it can be used on *any* element.

> The `id` attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID).
>   […]
>   Note: An element's unique identifier can be used for a variety of purposes, most notably as a way **to link to specific parts of a document using fragment identifiers**, as a way to target an element when scripting, and as a way to style a specific element from CSS.

Answer (score 3):

you should use `id=""` attribute. :)

Answer (score 1):

*(Note: migrated from https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/30031/10884 and edited for brevity.)*

If you need to jump users to in-page links, also known as **fragment identifiers**, you can set the `id` attribute (which is [used for more than just frag ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001236/why-should-one-add-id-to-their-html-tags/13001519#13001519)) on *any* element. Then use the usual `#` in the URL of a `href` attribute of an `a` element. Here’s an example:

```
<body>
  <p>Despite the many
    <a href="#benefits-of-gum-chewing">benefits</a>
    you may experience while chewing gum, there are also many drawbacks,
    especially with 
    <a href="http://www.example.org/sugar.html#cons">non-sugarless</a>
    gum.</p>
  ...
  <section id="benefits-of-gum-chewing">
    <h1>Benefits of Gum Chewing</h1>
    ...
  </section>
</body>
```

When writing my own pages, I like to give an `id` to each `<section>` tag (HTML5), even if I don’t plan on using it. The value of the `id` is a URL-friendly version of its heading’s content. You can achieve the same effect by assigning the same `id` to an `<h1>`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using id is not always ideal as they are unique, for example if you have a list of links as menu items and you want to perform some javascript on only certain ones of them when the user hovers over, using id's would be a mess.

Currently the best way I believe is using a *class* to identify them as a group.So something like this:

```
<a class="mylink">Menu Item one</a>
<a class="mylink">Menu Item two</a>
<a class="mylink">Menu Item three</a>
<a>Menu Item four</a>
```

But I've just kept on using the name tag, its stupid to deprecate something this minor as it has no performance effect or anything else, just causes problems if browsers decide not to accept the name tag at one moment. It strays us away from using standards as well.

Comment: This question is about using fragment URLs to link to an element. It seems reasonable to require that this ID be unique!