# Validation error, obsolete attribute

Tags: javascript, html, tags, obsolete

I'm currently working on a web page. Everything is working but when I went to validate, I ran into an error. The W3C validator says the *name* attribute is obsolete. Everything works, but no errors would be nice.

line from About_me.html

```
<img name="slide" alt="images about me" width="600" height="400">
```

line from slideshow.JS

```
function changeImg(){
    document.slide.src = images[i];
```

When I go to validate I get the following error "The *name* attribute on the img element is obsolete. Use the *id* attribute instead."
When I change *name* to *id* the slide show no longer works. What to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If <a name="..."> is obsolete, what is preferred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974480/if-a-name-is-obsolete-what-is-preferred)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the field of the img element from name to id, then you will have to use

```
document.getElementById("slide").src = images[i];
```

instead of just

```
document.slide.src = images[i];
```

Hope this helps! :D