# How does this shorthand of the code work without getElement method can someone please explain and tell more abou this analogy

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-objects

I was going through my book and found a piece of code which does not uses the traditional `getElement` method for selection but there is some shorthand used. Can some tell me more about this thing I know nothing of it `frm.txt.value`.

```js
function  show_temp(){
    var Tval=frm.txt.value;
    alert("The temp in far. is " + Tval + " degree");
}
```

```html
<form name="frm">
  Enter the temp in Fahrenheit:
  <input type="text" name="txt">
  <input type="button" value="temperature" onclick="show_temp()">
</form>
```

Comment: How old is that book?

Comment: There's a great, thorough explanation in section 15.9.1 Selecting Forms and Form Elements in JavaScript: The Definitive Guide. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms

Comment: Dont know it's just a part of my school curriculum so I have to study it non the less examiners here arent a fan for some new or different method. Of writting the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shorthand you are referring to relates to the `name` attribute of the `form` and the `input` - [this can be used to reference elements in JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_name.asp) and can be used as an alternative to `getElementById` etc.

```js
    function  show_temp(){
             console.log(frm.txt);
         }
```

```html
    <form name="frm">
            Enter the temp in Fahrenheit:
            <input type="text" name="txt">
            <input type="button" value="temperature" onclick="show_temp()">
        </form>
```

However, it is not recommended - unlike an `id`, a `name` attribute [can be repeated throughout the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974480/if-a-name-is-obsolete-what-is-preferred), so referencing `frm.txt` in this 2nd snippet below would actually return an array of results rather than a single result (click the temperature button on both for a comparison).

```js
    function  show_temp(){
             console.log(frm.txt);
         }
```

```html
    <form name="frm">
            Enter the temp in Fahrenheit:
            <input type="text" name="txt">
            <input type="text" name="txt">
            <input type="button" value="temperature" onclick="show_temp()">
        </form>
```