# can I apply IDs more than once in CSS?

Tags: css, html, xhtml

This is a beginner's question, but I need to clarify it.
Yes according to most of the tutorials it cannot be applied more than once.

**ID's are unique 

    Each element can have only one ID 

    Each page can have only one element with that ID**
Reference 
http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

But I wrote a simple mark-up in HTML and applied some CSS.

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ID vs Classes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ID & Classes.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="forh1">This is a h1 header</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

    <h1 id="forh1">This is a h1 header</h1>

    <p>Curabitur sodales ligula</p>

    <h2 id="forh1">This is a h2 header</h2> 
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#forh1{
text-align:center;


}
```

I have applied the same ID more than once (3 times). Two times in h1 header and one time in h2 header. When I run it in browser (chrome & firefox) they worked perfectly. All text in h1 and h2 headers were aligned center. Why is that ?  Have not I grasped ID concept properly or is it an issue with the browser? Because I have heard modern browsers are smart enough to understand most of the implicit things. Please help.

Comment: Please use a `class` instead of `id` also, spaces and special characters in file names are not recommended.

Comment: Good luck when you would wan to fetch the element using `getElementById` in js

Comment: The question asks why broken markup works (or seems to work) in conjunction with CSS. This is speculative and theoretical, not a practical coding problem. The question would be on-topic (though a duplicate) if it asked how you can apply some CSS rules to some selected elements only.

Comment: You have not grasped the ID concept properly. There are [many uses for ids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001236/why-should-one-add-id-to-their-html-tags/13001519#13001519). All require uniqueness except CSS selectors. In all other cases only the first element with the id is matched.

Comment: JavaScript cares not for your seemingly working CSS - JavaScript will hurt you for doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ID's are meant to use for identifying elements uniquely, they will work as far as CSS goes, but when JavaScript comes into action, you will understand why not to do so.

CSS just selects the element, when you write a matching selector, it has nothing to do with valid or invalid HTML you write, the job of CSS is to apply styles as per the selector defined. For example

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gPj3J/) **INVALID HTML, DO NOT USE IT** *(only for demonstration purpose)*

---

Hence, `ID`'s should be unique,, use `class` if you want to use the same properties on multiple elements.

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique
>   in a document.

---

Side tip: Use `_` instead of spaces <s>`href="ID & Classes.css"`</s> should be `href="IDs_Classes.css"`.

[Here's a good read, on why not to do that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/127180) *(So won't repeat here)*

Answer (score 6):

You can use ids more than once. The browser will still apply the styles. It is, however, not best practice to do so and is classed as invalid markup.

To get around it you can add a class to the element. Classes can be used on as many elements as you want.

Check the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and it throws the error `duplicate ids`

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: Yes, you can apply IDs more than once, as your test has proven.

HOWEVER!

Even though this works as expected in your test in modern browsers, you are not guaranteed for it work in older browsers, or IE for that manner. Neither are you guaranteed that javascript functions like getElementByID will work as intended. As others have answered: Multiple IDs in html is considered bad practice and a misuse of the concept of class & ids.

Comment: In [DOM Living Standard](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/), getElementById is currently guaranteed to return the element with the first matching ID in document order; the behavior is not-defined in DOM Level 2/3. (I have no idea which browsers/versions follow the "Living Standard".)

Answer (score 0):

**For Html and Css:-** 
In CSS code page,
Consider, you have created a style for a ID. 
In Html Page, 
You can apply the style of that ID many times as per your wish.

But, **For Javascript and JQuery:-** 
If you use same ID to more than one field, then you cannot validate that field. 
Because, ID must be unique to perform operations on Javascript and JQuery. 
 
I hope you understand.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest appying css to you tags first as it makes updating your pages much easier

```
h1 {

 text-align:center;

}
```