# document.getElementById - dynamic use for using the same ID more than once

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    modalImg.alt = this.alt;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
```

```css
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="imageone.jpg" alt="Image one" >

<br>
<br>
<img id="myImg" src="imagetwo.jpg" alt="Image two" >
```

So the above snippet is used in the modal image css3 tutorial. I understand i cannot have more than  one tags with the same ID which is why the code online works with one image. After researching i know i have to use a dyamic ID with JS.

```js
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
```

The previous JS line is what i need to change.

How does one dynamically change getElementById? So that i can use more then one  with differentr src images?

Research shows Using a Tag selector or a class selector is inappropriate.

Any help documents to aid in my learning will be great as well.

---

So i made some nice progress with the css and stuff and it looks great. Now my next step is to use existing alts to include text when the modal appears. Below is the existing js line i had already

var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

Now below is the html i will use when calling alt so that each image has its own alt text appearing under the modal pop up

I've tried it and doesnt seem to work, could it be my formatting in the css?

Comment: Using a classname selector is appropiate. Inappropiate is use duplicated ids. Ids are **unique** in each document, and `getElementById` will return only one element even if you set several same ids.

Comment: [Here's a previous answer to your question.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21495673/1769777)

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the link, Will study it as well

Answer (score 5):

If there's a collection of elements that need to be processed the same, it's best to use the `class` attribute to target them.

Instead of targeting one element with: `document.getElementById`, you get a `NodeList`, which is a collection of elements, using `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.querySelectorAll`.

Then, you need to loop through these elements and use the code you've already written.

Here's an example:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i += 1) {
  var img = imgs[i];

  img.onclick = function() {
    // your on click stuff
  };
};
```

Don't forget to change the HTML to: `<img class="myImg" src="imageone.jpg" alt="Image one" >`

Comment: If i'm correct. Are you using a for loop to go over an array?

Comment: The elements are stored in a nodelist, which is technically not an array but resembles it in some ways. Mainly, it has a length property and you can select elements from it using [index]. Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is helpful for you

```js
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-img');

if (imgs) {

  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].addEventListener('click', showModal, false);
  }

}

function showModal() {
  var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
  if (modal) {
    var img = modal.querySelector('img');
    var close = modal.querySelector('.close');
    modal.classList.add('open');
    img.src = this.src;

    if (close) {
      close.addEventListener('click', closeModal, false);
    }
  }
}

function closeModal() {
  this.parentNode.classList.remove('open');
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
img:hover {
  border: 2px solid #191919;
}
.modal {
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px;
}
.modal.open {
  display: inline-block;
}
.modal .close {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<img class='gallery-img' src="http://wallpaperbeta.com/wallpaper/small_fish_by_name_beta_minimalism_hd-wallpaper-296364.jpg" alt="">

<img class='gallery-img' src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/flowers_small_flower_surface_rose_43393_2048x1152.jpg" alt="">

<div class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, Just a few questions. I notice that all img tags will be affected. How do go around preventing for images i with to be "Just there". I've tried using a class div and placing background on it but it sometimes work and sometimes does. I have updated the top

Comment: @Pandee i changed my answer check it now

Comment: Sorry! I found out my images lacked the width and height so they "vanished"

Comment: Hello, could you explain why and how you made those changes to create an alt text appear?? As the snipper no longer works.