# How to disable button in table rows when admins select approve button and click submit button, and also after refreshing?

Tags: javascript, php

I am basically doing an interface where admins are able to approve and reject records by clicking the approve button and reject button on every table row. But I have a few criteria :

After admin click on approve button, followed by the submit button, the reject button should be disabled and kept permanent, even after refresh no changes are allowed in the future. Which means to say, the table should show approved on that row. If admin clicks on reject button, the table should state reject on that row.

What I have done :
Each table row has a approve and reject button. But the disable function is not working as what I want. The disable button functions only work for the first row in the table.

**My PHP code:**

```
for($x=0; $x<$i; $x++)
{
   echo "<tr>
<td>". $recordid[$x] ."</td>
<td>". $datetime[$x]."</td>
<td>". $recordid[$x] ."</td>

<td>
    <button type= 'button' class='btn btn-success' name='".$selectedradio[x]."' id='accept' onClick='myFunction()'>Approve</button>
</td>

<td>
    <button type= 'button' class='btn btn-danger' name='".$selectedradio[x]."' id='reject' onClick='myFunction()'>Reject</button>
</td>

}
```

**My JS Code:**

```
function myFunction(){
   document.getElementByClassName('btn btn-success').setAttribute('disabled',true)
   document.getElementByClassName('btn btn-danger').setAttribute('disabled',true)
}
```

Comment: learn ajax and jquery

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, so you need to go and fix that first of all. (And -1 for “this is urgent”. No, it’s not.)

Comment: @misorude sure, already changed it :)

Comment: [its because id can only used once in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495626/can-i-apply-ids-more-than-once-in-css) but you can use the class in your javascript

Comment: @Kyubidin123 noted, I have changed from using the id to using the class. But, it still doesn't work.

Comment: As its in a loop, you need to have the accept/reject status per row. You can disable based on the status in the loop.

Comment: @VinuBibin hi , yes right now on each row there is the reject and accept button. Sorry I dont quite understand what you mean by disable based on status in the loop.

Comment: You can disable the button based on the status for each row

Comment: If your table data comes from a database, you could add there a column 'status' and then check on your page whether this datarow is approved or rejected to know which button must be disabled ... I think that is what VinuBibin meant too :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather doing it with id you should use class like this:

```
       document.getElementByClassName('reject').setAttribute('disabled',true);
       document.getElementByClassName('accept').setAttribute('disabled',true);
```

Add a class reject and accept in your html.I recommend jquery.

Comment: There should be a flag from your database to check the status of the row. In reference to remove the reject status.Then on click of the button update that status to database using ajax refresh to show current status

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
 function enableButton2() {
 document.getElementById("button2").disabled = True;
 }
 </script>
 </head>
     <body>
         <input type="button" id="button1" value="button 1" onclick="enableButton2()"  />
         <input type="button" id="button2" value="button 2" />
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanations.