# Why do we use id in html. I think we can use a class as an id

Tags: html, css

Why do we use id in html. I think we can use a class as an id. If class can select one or more elements then there is no point of using any id.
My Question is quite clear.I just wanted to know why do we use id ? Is class is not enough for the purpose?

Comment: `Id` ensures uniqueness, which is often desired.

Comment: Findout the meaning for the term **UNIQUE** which will help to know about `id`

Comment: @aksu I think only one element can also be selected by class.

Comment: @Praveen Plz tell me the meaning of uniqueness

Comment: Is this an attempt at an April Fool's joke?  An `id` is a unique identifier, a `class` is a non-unique descriptor.  The two are different things, used for different reasons.

Comment: Lols..Today is not 1st April and also I donot celebrate fool day.

Comment: [List of uses of the id attribute in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001236/why-should-one-add-id-to-their-html-tags/13001519#13001519)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can. Certainly. But...

```
<h1 id="jump_here">Target</h1>
> http://example.com/somepage.html#jump_here
```

This would not work with a class.

---

```
document.getElementById('jump_here'); // fully compatible
document.getElementsByClassName('jump_here')[0]; // IE9+
document.querySelector(".jump_here"); // IE8+
(function() {for(var a=document.all,l=a.length,i=0,ret=[];i<l;i++)
        if(a[i].className.match(/\bjump_here\b/))ret.push(a[i]);return ret;})();
// fully compatible
```

Do you really want to write all that just to get one element?

Comment: I donot know about jquery or any other web languages.I think for a html document only using class is enough.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, every element on your web page can be assigned a **unique id attribute**. This can be any text you like, but it has to be unique **(only one item can have this label)**. It's a good practice to assign labels that describe the function of the element. For example, a `<ul>` that's used to markup a **navigation menu might** have `id="navigation"` or `id="menu"`

So far you have added `style` to various elements in your portfolio page, but the `styles` **you've** added have affected **all elements** of a particular type. **For example**, when you added `style` to the `div` element that affected all `div` elements equally. What if you want to **stylize** some div elements one way, and other `div` elements a different way?

**more about** **[div and class](http://www.washington.edu/accesscomputing/webd2/student/unit3/module5/lesson1.html)**

Comment: You could still use `class` instead of `id` in your example

Comment: now click to the more about div and class http://www.washington.edu/accesscomputing/webd2/student/unit3/module5/lesson1.html and id mention about this link

Answer (score 0):

Woah there. This is a rather sweeping generalisation.

[Have a read](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-class-id-css/) of this post, it is quite informative.

It also saves me re-stating his points.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460644/in-jquery-is-selecting-by-class-or-id-faster-than-selecting-by-some-other-attri) is also good at looking from a Javascript point of view.

Answer (score 0):

What if you want to select a specific element in JavaScript? You would need to use a

```
var x=document.getElementById("myHeader");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp

Also, check this out:

http://css-tricks.com/why-use-classes-or-ids-on-the-html-element/

If you want to use one CSS doc on multiple pages, you may want things to be different on pages. Use id tags.

Comment: HTML by itself, is pretty much useless. When people give you an answer to your question, they are telling you things that you will eventually come to know. HTML + CSS + JS is pretty much standard in styling and displaying web.

Answer (score 0):

> just wanted to know why do we use id ? Is class is not enough for the purpose?

Its very simple, *for performance concern*.  Here I have created test scripts to check their performance for the below code in [**jsperf.com**](http://jsperf.com/difference-between-id-and-class)

See the below example

```
<ul>
  <li class="sheep">WHITE SHEEP</li>
  <li class="sheep">WHITE SHEEP</li>
  <li id="black" class="sheep">BlACK SHEEP</li>
  <li class="sheep">WHITE SHEEP</li>
  <li class="sheep">WHITE SHEEP</li>
</ul>
```

Now I need to get the `li` element of BLACK SHEEP.

If you go for class, then you will write the code as

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("sheep");
```

the is returns an *array of all elements with class name `sheep`,* so to find the `BLACK SHEEP` you need to loop through

```
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
  if (list[i].innerHTML === "BLACK SHEEP") {
    // Here you will get the black sheep
  }
}
```

To reduce the burden, they introduced the id selector.

```
var black = document.getElementById("black").innerHTML;  //so simple right
```

Know you understand the term UNIQUENESS right?