# Is there any way to make IDs unique to any element on the page, not to the document

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to google, but failed.

I want the element with an ID to be unique relatively to, for example, his parent, not to the document itself. Is there a way to do that?

Ok, since you need an example. I have a huge form, with tons of radio buttons and inputs, e.g.: 2 radio buttons with IDs. Each with label.

```
<input type="radio" id="foo" name="name">
<label for="foo">Never</label>

<input type="radio" id="bar" name="name">
<label for="bar">Daily</label>
```

I can not afford to change this setup.

And I have a button that clones (via `.clone()`) this form.

As you may guess, it all breaks, because IDs and labels are not unique.

Comment: Yes. Use `class`es. `id`s are only for elements that *only appear once on a page*, such as a global container or a "logout" link.

Comment: Please include an example - otherwise - I recommend using the IDs of parent elements and creating Ids based off of those.

Comment: You could also use multipart ids like `id="parentElement-idValue"`. depending on how you want to use them

Comment: @JoshuaChavanne included.

Comment: So to glean the core requirements,  you are cloning an entire form from one area on the page and want to have it display elsewhere with no ID conflicts?

I suggest using a combo of mine and JRulle's comments - you want to snag the ID of the parent element that you are cloning into - and then use Jquery to clone the whole form, at this point I'd use jQuery again to take the Ids of every element in the form and append the parent containers' ID.  Its not a pretty solution, but ought to work.

Comment: You might want to reconsider the approach https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer guess so, with my current setup it will probably be worthless to write a script that would dynamically change the IDs of the radios and labels, preserving their unique name, like "foo-1", "bar-1". Things I've seen and wrote only change it dynamically to "foo-1", "foo-1" in one form and "foo-2", "foo-2" in the other.

Comment: @JoshuaChavanne—please, jQuery is not the solution to every problem. The OP wishes to clone a radio button and wants to know how to ensure it has a unique ID to match its associated label. If the OP is using jQuery (perhaps, since `.clone()` is mentioned), the question should be tagged as such.

Comment: @RobG clone is a method in jQuery so I assumed that was implied. At the very least hopefully he gets the basic principle of prepending the parent ID).

Answer (score 0):

***Edit***: the OP totally changed his question after my answer. Please look at the edit history before assuming I was off topic

If you are tempted to use the same ID for multiple items, you need to use a class. You can target classes within specific parent nodes. For example, in jQuery:

```
var elem = $('.parentClass .childClass');
```

This would target only items of .childClass that are children of .parentClass. You could select other instances of .childClass with different parent elements by changing the parent element in the CSS selector.

```
var eleme = $('.otherParentClass .childClass');
```

Comment: Misses the point of the question. Id attributes are being used to associate the label with its control.

Comment: The OP totally edited his question far after I had already answered. Look at the edit history.

Comment: OK, but your answer still didn't address the question as asked. And in general, you shouldn't assume that classes can be substituted for ids. There are many uses for id attributes in HTML, almost all of which cannot be substituted by a class. There's [a list of uses of id here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001236/why-should-one-add-id-to-their-html-tags#13001519)

Comment: The OP was asking about using non-unique IDs within a document (unique to the parent, not the document) which is not a valid use of the ID attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Radio inputs can be placed inside labels. With this setup, you don't need an `id` for the radio to match the `for` of the label, and the label will work as expected (clicking it activates the radio input). This removes the need for you to create a unique `for-id` pair.

```html
<label>
  Here's teh label
  <input type="radio" name="foo">
</label>

<label>
  Here's another label
  <input type="radio" name="foo">
</label>
```

Comment: I appreciate that, and I know that such a thing possible, but I use custom checkboxes and they only are maintained via setup I have.

Comment: @user3785004 I sense you have custom images for the checkboxes. You can probably tweak the CSS, if that's an option.

Comment: There were versions of IE that didn't honour labels without a for attribute, even when enclosing the related control. Can't remember when or if that's been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The following is just a suggestion of an algorithm with some working code, there is logic missing from the question regarding how to determine where to insert the cloned element. I've modified the name of the controls since giving a control a name of *name* masks the form's own *name* property.

The id is generated based on the number of controls in the form with the same name. Perhaps you have some other algorithm.

```
function cloneRadio(control) {

  // Create a document fragment for convenience
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

  // Clone the control and add to fragment
  var el = frag.appendChild(control.cloneNode());

  // Get all the controls in the form with the same name
  var controls = control.form[control.name];

  // Give the new control an id of name + control count
  el.id = control.name + controls.length;

  // Add a label
  var label = frag.appendChild(document.createElement('label'));

  // Add text in label
  label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('for ' + el.id));

  // Link label to element
  label.htmlFor = el.id;

  // Add to end of form
  control.form.appendChild(frag);
}
```

This assumes that you aren't removing any elements, that will mess with the numbering if you do. I've just put the cloned element at the end of the form, you'll need some way of working out where to put it but haven't mentioned it here.

Some related HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="button" value="clone foo" 
   onclick="cloneRadio(this.form.controlName[0]);">
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="foo" name="controlName">
  <label for="foo">Never</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="bar" name="controlName">
  <label for="bar">Daily</label>
</form>
```