# are element id's avoided in modern web dev?

Tags: html, css, web

I seem to remember reading or someone telling me that modern web dev practices tend to avoid assigning id's to elements in lieu of classes or data-attributes.  Is this correct or am I possibly misinterpreting this practice based on my experience in one particular scenario?

Comment: Nope! You can see for yourself by going to a bunch of different websites and searching the source code for "id=". You can technically do just about anything with getElementsByClassName and $(".class") instead of getElementByIdName and $("#id"), but a combination of both is usually the best way to go.

Comment: A quick Google search for "css class vs id" or something similar would reveal a very large body of discussion about the topic.

Comment: you can google it... though I do not think it's true such thing

Answer (score 1):

No.

They are used all the time. Depends on the angle you look at it.

In terms of CSS selectors, the answer is often a Yes. IDs are more likely to be avoided in CSS as they make the CSS selector's specificity too high.

IDs are great for JavaScript as a means to *"hook into"* the markup. They're an easy way to get the element you want without having to resort to searching through a result set.

```js
var el  = document.getElementById( 'example' );
var el  = document.querySelector( '#example' );
var $el = $( '#example' ); // jQuery
```

#### Edit

Plus many target related uses and others benefit from an ID, link via Alohci.

[User for ID attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001236/why-should-one-add-id-to-their-html-tags#13001519)

Comment: In addition, it's often forgotten just how many other [uses there are for id attributes in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001236/why-should-one-add-id-to-their-html-tags#13001519)

Comment: @Alohci yes, very true. Thanks for the link.