# Naming HTML <section> id's

Tags: html, css

I just got a html template with sections and a few things are not clear about them.

The file contains a section look like this:

```
<section id="section-name" class="row"> 

</section>
```

As I already found simple `<section> </section>` tags, I'm confused about a few things. Mainly, what does the section id's? Are they referring to CSS rules or they can be used without any connection with the CSS? So far I couldn't find anything in my CSS file related to the used section names so I assume the id's are named based on practical reasons that helps to structure the code.

Am I right that section id's don't have any connections with CSS? Or they can refer to CSS options but they can also work without any CSS related connection?

Comment: IDs don't need to be tied to CSS. Then can also be used in JavaScript or not used it either.

Comment: ID is not specific to section. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) has a lot of good information.

Comment: The `id` attribute specifies a unique identifier for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).
It is most used to point to a style in a style sheet, and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with the specific ID.

Comment: id with # or . with classname as we use for div's are the better ways of applying css properties with html.But I don't see anything much different by using a section tag.Section is not a good option used for wrapping.Read this once http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/

Comment: [Eleven uses for Id in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001236/why-should-one-add-id-to-their-html-tags#13001519)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `id` attribute on a section does exactly the same as it does on every other element.

- You can link to it with a fragment identifier on the end of a URL
- You can target it with CSS
- You can target it with a programming language (e.g. client side JavaScript).

There is nothing unique to sections about how the `id` attribute is handled.

Comment: Could easily be a target for an aria-describedby attribute too.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as an ID on any other tag. You don't have to use it in CSS, but you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sections in css like this:
css:

```
section
{
color:red;
}
```

or

```
section#section-name
{
color:red;
}
```

or

```
section.row
{
color:red;
}
```

or

```
section#section-name.row
{
color:red;
}
```